# Data loss after running Bash script creating dirs and moving files

Tags: bash, scripts, nautilus, nemo

For several instances now, I experienced some very weird behavior, where part of the directories and the files in a directory got deleted after running a script which creates new directories within that directory and writes files to it.

The details about my system:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy

Linux ThinkPad-P16s-Gen-1 6.2.0-37-generic #38~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Thu Nov  2 18:01:13 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
tmpfs           1,6G  2,9M  1,6G   1% /run
/dev/nvme0n1p6  144G  132G  3,9G  98% /
tmpfs           7,7G   76M  7,6G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5,0M  4,0K  5,0M   1% /run/lock
/dev/nvme0n1p1  256M   58M  199M  23% /boot/efi
tmpfs           1,6G  132K  1,6G   1% /run/user/1001
/dev/nvme0n1p4  684G  429G  255G  63% /media/thomasrauter/Data1
```

For example, I ran a script that I usually run and were I already know that it works, and it worked the first time, then I ran it another time with another input and midway to the files it should process, the script itself, two other `.sh` scripts in that directory and half the other directories disappeared (they are not in the trash).

I had this problem in similar form in the past, where everything in a directory disappeared. I then ran `fsck` on that unmounted drive, nothing happened, but a few days later (worked on the computer and Ubuntu in these days) the files suddenly reappeared again.

Sometimes also, when a script writes several files to a directory, that directory does not show these files when running `ls`, and on the graphical user interface, it says it's loading but it never gets there. This stays like that even after I reboot.

Sorry, I cannot describe a concise problem, but my question is basically if anyone of you has seen anything like that before (I really think it has something to do with Nautilus or Nemo), because right now, my Ubuntu feels like a haunted house.

---

**Edit** (thank you of pointing out the issues of my question):

`ls -al /media/thomasrauter/` returns:

```
total 24
drwxr-x---+ 4 root         root          4096 Dez  1 15:47 .
drwxr-xr-x  4 root         root          4096 Jun  4 15:54 ..
drwxr-xr-x  2 root         root          4096 Aug 19 10:24 Data
drwxrwxrwx  1 thomasrauter thomasrauter 12288 Dez  1 14:53 Data1
```

This is the code of one of the scripts that causes trouble (but it is not the only script, and it always did its job before):

```
#!/bin/bash

# Check if eight arguments are provided
if [ "$#" -ne 7 ]; then
    echo "Usage: bash $0 <seq_platform> <depth> <length_min> <length_max> <length_mean> <length_sd> <accuracy_mean>"
    echo "bash simulate_reads.sh ONT 30 1000 100000 20000 10000 0.85"
    echo "bash simulate_reads.sh PacBio 30 1000 60000 15000 5000 0.90"
    exit 1
fi

# Assigning arguments to variables
seq_platform="$1"
depth="$2"
length_min="$3"
length_max="$4"
length_mean="$5"
length_sd="$6"
accuracy_mean="$7"

if [ "$seq_platform" == "ONT" ]; then
  model='QSHMM-ONT.model'
elif [ "$seq_platform" == "PacBio" ]; then
  model='QSHMM-RSII.model'
else
  echo "Error: Only ONT and PacBio supported as seq platform."
  exit 1
fi


# Check if the image exists locally
if [[ "$(docker images -q thomasrauter/pbsim3:1.0 2> /dev/null)" == "" ]]; then
    # If the image doesn't exist locally, pull it from Docker Hub
    docker pull thomasrauter/pbsim3:1.0
fi


# Create an array to store filenames
file_array=()

# Loop to find files ending with .fa or .fasta and add them to the array
for file in *.fa *.fasta; do
    if [ -e "$file" ]; then  # Check if file exists
        file_array+=("$file")
    fi
done


for fasta_filename in "${file_array[@]}"; do
  echo -e "\n#####################################################################################\n\n"
  echo -e"\nProcessing $fasta_filename"

  output_dir_name="${fasta_filename%%.*}_${seq_platform}_pbsim3_output_$(date +"%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S")"

  docker run --name pbsim3 \
    -v "$(pwd)/$fasta_filename":/pbsim3/input_files/input.fasta \
    thomasrauter/pbsim3:1.0 \
    pbsim --strategy wgs \
          --method qshmm \
          --qshmm data/"$model" \
          --depth "$depth" \
          --genome input_files/input.fasta
          --length-min "$3" \
          --length-max "$4" \
          --length-mean "$5" \
          --length-sd "$6" \
          --accuracy-mean "$7"

  docker cp pbsim3:"/pbsim3/output_files" "$(pwd)/$output_dir_name"
  docker rm pbsim3 > /dev/null 2>&1

  # Change to the specified directory
  cd "$output_dir_name" || exit 1  # Exit if the directory change fails

  # Create an array to store .fastq filenames
  local_fastq_files=()

  # Find all .fastq files and add them to the array
  for local_file in *.fastq; do
      if [ -e "$local_file" ]; then  # Check if file exists
          local_fastq_files+=("$local_file")
      fi
  done

  # Concatenate all files in the array into a single .fastq file
  local_combined_fastq="combined.fastq"  # Name of the output file
  cat "${local_fastq_files[@]}" > "$local_combined_fastq"

  # Write a file with the used parameters
  output_file="pbsim3_parameters.txt"

  # Write to the file
  {
      echo "Input_fasta_file: $fasta_filename"
      echo "Seq_platform: $seq_platform"
      echo "Depth: $depth"
      echo "Length_min: $length_min"
      echo "Length_max: $length_max"
      echo "Length_mean: $length_mean"
      echo "Length_sd: $length_sd"
      echo "Accuracy_mean: $accuracy_mean"
  } > "$output_file"

  cd .. || exit 1

  echo "Simulation of the reads for the file $fasta_file completed. The files are in the dir $output_dir_name in the current working dir."
done
```

Comment: Can you check dir `/media/thomasrauter/Data/`?

Comment: /media/thomasrauter/Data/       is empty (Contents: nothing; Volume: unknow; Free space: 20.6 GB) . It was once the mountpoint for my 700 GB SSD harddrive, but after an fsck (a few months ago) to deal with a corruped dir in my original Data dir, the dir Data1 got created by fsck as new mountpoint, and Data now is empty.      I hope that is the info you wanted to have.

Comment: This sounds more like a disk or filesystem error than anything else. Can you get the script to reproduce the issue reliably? Does it _always_ behave badly or only soetimes? Can you reduce this script to a minimal example that reproduces the issue? How do you launch the script? Note that `$(pwd)` wil be expanded to the directory you are currently in, so it will change depending on where you launch from. How do you launch the script? Do you do `script` or `sh script`? or `bash script`? or something else?

Comment: On an unrelated note, while I am less familiar with PacBio, I know ONT have made huge improvements in their sequencing quality in recent years, and `pbsim` [seems to be](https://github.com/pfaucon/PBSIM-PacBio-Simulator) 7 years old. Are you sure it is still capable of usefully simulating modern long read data?

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot reproduce the issue. It does only sometimes behave badly. I used this script several times, and it never caused an issue. However, I also other problems occur, like the additional ones that I described, or that files randomly move around, or, when trying to copy specific dirs, that should only be 150 MB big or so, it says preparing to copy: and then it infinitely counts up GB that it wants to copy. I think I might just have to save my data and format the whole drive, and hope that works, or otherwise, set Ubuntu up newly.

Comment: Back then when run fsck on that dir (data), before I had my system freezing because of some action in that dir, and I made a hard shut down, because I did not know REISUB yet, maybe I already messed it up back then.

Comment: Regarding pbsim, I am using a Docker container where I have cloned the Github page of pbsim3, which was I think updated only a year or two ago, so I hope that will give me good enough reads.  But thank you very much for your time and for pointing these things out.